# 3.3V to 15V PWM converter

Tags: pwm, level-shifting, schmitt-trigger

I have the good old problem of converting a *3.3V logic* voltage to a *higher voltage*.
Higher means everything between 12 and 20V. With *15V* being used most of the time.
The highest frequency I use now is *5kHz*. I don't want to redesign this if it's 10khz in the future.
It is prototyping hardware to simulate some rotary encoders with errors. I will build 6-7 boards with 8 channels each. So I would prefer IC's over discrete builds.
The logic input should be (way) below 1mA per channel. The circuit will need to deliver 20mA max, some headroom would be nice. I have build one with SN74. Which works ok up to 14-15V. Now I'm looking forward to use CD40109BE.
Does anyone want to share some experience in this regard? My current research is:
Discrete: doable but too much work on PCB / soldering
OPAMP: haven't found a good one
Schmitt trigger: works fine but higher voltage seems to be a problem
Optocoupler: difficult with speed and channels
Buffer IC: CD4050B / CD40109BE
Gate Driver: very robust maybe UC17/27/37 from TI?

I kinda like the idea of the Gate Driver if I need a variable Power Supply somewhere down the road. But I think the right Schmitt Trigger or Buffer IC does the job perfectly fine. Just need to find the one IC ^^

Comment: The CD40109BE has an upper limit of 20V out. If your output voltage has an error of 0.0001% above 20V, the level shifter will be out-of-spec and may start to be damaged. You need to find a different part.

Comment: Can your output be interrupted-ground open-drain? In other words, can you get away with a simple N-channel array?

Comment: Also, optocoupler speed is absolutely not an issue at 10kHz.